# Scaled Bitmap maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling

I would like to scale a `Bitmap` to a runtime dependant width and height, where the aspect ratio is maintained and the `Bitmap` fills the entire width and centers the image vertically, either cropping the excess or filling in the gap with 0 alpha pixels.

I'm currently redrawing the bitmap myself by creating a `Bitmap` of all 0 alpha pixels and drawing the image `Bitmap` on top of it, scaling to the exact specified width and maintaining the aspect ratio, however, it ends up losing/screwing up the pixel data.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Config.ARGB_8888);
float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth(), originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
float scale = width/originalWidth;
float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale)/2.0f;
Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, null);
return background;
```

Is there a library out there or some better code that can do this better? I would like the image to look as crisp as possible, but I knew that my function wouldn't provide a great result.

I know I could have the image stay fine by using integer scaling, instead of float scaling, but I need the width to be 100% filled.

Also, I know about an `ImageView`'s `Gravity.CENTER_CROP` capability, however, that also uses integer scaling, so it cuts off the width of the image when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

What about this:

```
Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Config.ARGB_8888);

float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth(); 
float originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

float scale = width / originalWidth;

float xTranslation = 0.0f;
float yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;

Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
transformation.preScale(scale, scale);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);

return background;
```

I added a `paint` to filter the scaled bitmap.

Comment: Well, the scale can't change, as I need the width to be filled and it can't crop the width, either. However, the paint did the trick. Thank you! Can you edit the answer to switch back to my scaling?

Comment: but it is cropping image

Comment: This is it! Finally

Comment: it crops the landscaped or potrait images to fit into square :(

Answer (score 133):

This will respect maxWidth and maxHeight, which means the resulting bitmap will never have dimensions larger then those:

```
 private static Bitmap resize(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        int finalWidth = maxWidth;
        int finalHeight = maxHeight;
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float)maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float)maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
        }
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
        return image;
    } else {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer of solution crop the image but this solution work perfect.

Comment: @Arslan I didn't get any cropping with this method. Can you elaborate a little more.

Comment: @JoshPinter "The accepted answer to this question caused cropping. This answer works perfectly for me as it does not cause cropping."

Comment: if my width and height is 1200x1200 and my max width and height is 700x700 rationBitmap and rationMax both are 0.0 so this is a valid condition or not because then after it will be making divided by zero exception

Comment: perfect to me :)

Comment: @KishanDonga in those cases ratio is 1, not 0... in fact the ratio is obtained dividing the width by the height, so it can never be 0 (unless the width is 0, which makes no sense).

Comment: ok this is working fine. I am also expecting different varient which does not scale up the image if image dimension is already lower then the given max height width.

Answer (score 33):

here is a method from my Utils class, that does the job:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmapAndKeepRation(Bitmap targetBmp,int reqHeightInPixels,int reqWidthInPixels)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix .setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, targetBmp.getWidth(), targetBmp.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, reqWidthInPixels, reqHeightInPixels), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetBmp, 0, 0, targetBmp.getWidth(), targetBmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: **Note** that this is API 17 (Jellybean) or higher only

Comment: Neat !! . That was just simple . except the variable naming convention. better change TargetBmp -> targetBmp. Worked for both **portrait** and **landscape** images

Comment: Bitmap quality loses when we scale bitmap using this method. Not worked for me. Please give me another solution.

Comment: @RishavSingla You are requesting a solution to the inherent cost of resizing an image. It's not a vector. Resizing is a lossy operation.

Answer (score 26):

Here I have a tested solution where I create a scaled Bitmap out of a bitmap file:

```
    int scaleSize =1024;

    public Bitmap resizeImageForImageView(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
        int originalWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        int newWidth = -1;
        int newHeight = -1;
        float multFactor = -1.0F;
        if(originalHeight > originalWidth) {
            newHeight = scaleSize ;
            multFactor = (float) originalWidth/(float) originalHeight;
            newWidth = (int) (newHeight*multFactor);
        } else if(originalWidth > originalHeight) {
            newWidth = scaleSize ;
            multFactor = (float) originalHeight/ (float)originalWidth;
            newHeight = (int) (newWidth*multFactor);
        } else if(originalHeight == originalWidth) {
            newHeight = scaleSize ;
            newWidth = scaleSize ;
        }
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Notice that I need scaled Bitmaps which have a maximum size of 4096x4096 Pixels but the aspect ratio needs to be kept while resizing. If you need other values for width or height just replace the values "4096".

This is just an addition to the answer of Coen but the problem in his code is the line where he calculates the ratio. Dividing two Integers gives an Integer and if the result is < 1 it will be rounded to 0. So this throws the "divide by zero" exception.

Comment: I would suggest to extract the new size value to a variable or parameter to avoid repetition. Also you could initialize newWidth and newHeight with the new size value and only re-set the variable that changes to preserve the scale (also multFactor or resizedBitmap doesn't need to be pre-initialized).

Comment: You are definitely right @Christopher Reichel, above code do not scale all of the sizes, just ones which have higher width than height. Thiis answer is better but the answer of @ joaomgcd is better than this because of the code optimization and method parameters.

Comment: does it stretch the image. If I want to resize the image to fit into a square and respect the aspect ratio. Expecting to leave unused area transparent.

Answer (score 14):

None of the above answers worked for me and I just created a method that sets all of the dimensions into the desired ones by painting the empty area black. Here is my method:

```
/**
 * Scale the image preserving the ratio
 * @param imageToScale Image to be scaled
 * @param destinationWidth Destination width after scaling
 * @param destinationHeight Destination height after scaling
 * @return New scaled bitmap preserving the ratio
 */
public static Bitmap scalePreserveRatio(Bitmap imageToScale, int destinationWidth,
        int destinationHeight) {
    if (destinationHeight > 0 && destinationWidth > 0 && imageToScale != null) {
        int width = imageToScale.getWidth();
        int height = imageToScale.getHeight();

        //Calculate the max changing amount and decide which dimension to use
        float widthRatio = (float) destinationWidth / (float) width;
        float heightRatio = (float) destinationHeight / (float) height;

        //Use the ratio that will fit the image into the desired sizes
        int finalWidth = (int)Math.floor(width * widthRatio);
        int finalHeight = (int)Math.floor(height * widthRatio);
        if (finalWidth > destinationWidth || finalHeight > destinationHeight) {
            finalWidth = (int)Math.floor(width * heightRatio);
            finalHeight = (int)Math.floor(height * heightRatio);
        }

        //Scale given bitmap to fit into the desired area
        imageToScale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageToScale, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);

        //Created a bitmap with desired sizes
        Bitmap scaledImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(destinationWidth, destinationHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledImage);

        //Draw background color
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

        //Calculate the ratios and decide which part will have empty areas (width or height)
        float ratioBitmap = (float)finalWidth / (float)finalHeight;
        float destinationRatio = (float) destinationWidth / (float) destinationHeight;
        float left = ratioBitmap >= destinationRatio ? 0 : (float)(destinationWidth - finalWidth) / 2;
        float top = ratioBitmap < destinationRatio ? 0: (float)(destinationHeight - finalHeight) / 2;
        canvas.drawBitmap(imageToScale, left, top, null);

        return scaledImage;
    } else {
        return imageToScale;
    }
}
```

For example;

Let's say you have an image as 100 x 100 but the desired size is 300x50, then this method will convert your image to 50 x 50 and paint it into a new image that has dimensions of 300 x 50 (and empty fields will be black).

Another example: let's say you have an image as 600 x 1000 and the desired sizes are 300 x 50 again, then your image will be converted into 30 x 50 and painted into a newly created image which has sizes of 300 x 50.

I think this is what it must be, Rs.

Comment: perfect answer for my use case

Comment: good, worked for my use case too. To calculate the width and height effectively.

Comment: i voted it up because this does the both jobs, making the bitmap scaled without losing aspect ratio and also centering the bitmap.

Comment: Wow finally... This is what I was looking for desparetly. Btw I used Color.TRANSPARENT for transparency.

Comment: You are well served :) @CrackerKSR

Comment: @bahadir-tasdemir it would be off topic but can you suggest anything to encode these frames into animated webp. I am looking for animated webp encoder after trying few image libraries

Comment: That's a topic that I am very unfamiliar with, sorry but I have no idea, I must investigate as you do.

Answer (score 9):

simpler solution : note we set the width to 500 pixels

```
 public void scaleImageKeepAspectRatio()
    {
        int imageWidth = scaledGalleryBitmap.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = scaledGalleryBitmap.getHeight();
        int newHeight = (imageHeight * 500)/imageWidth;
        scaledGalleryBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(scaledGalleryBitmap, 500, newHeight, false);

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

It can also be done by calculating the ratio yourself, like this.

```
private Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    Log.v("Pictures", "Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

    if (width > height) {
        // landscape
        int ratio = width / maxWidth;
        width = maxWidth;
        height = height / ratio;
    } else if (height > width) {
        // portrait
        int ratio = height / maxHeight;
        height = maxHeight;
        width = width / ratio;
    } else {
        // square
        height = maxHeight;
        width = maxWidth;
    }

    Log.v("Pictures", "after scaling Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: If you downscale, ratio is 0, it throws a Exception dividing by 0

Comment: yeah whatever, its the solution that counts right? vultures are always ready to downvote ideas here....sigh :-)

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin extension function version based on joaomgcd's answer

```
private fun Bitmap.resize(maxWidth: Int, maxHeight: Int): Bitmap {
    return if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        val width = this.width
        val height = this.height
        val ratioBitmap = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
        val ratioMax = maxWidth.toFloat() / maxHeight.toFloat()
        var finalWidth = maxWidth
        var finalHeight = maxHeight
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (maxHeight.toFloat() * ratioBitmap).toInt()
        } else {
            finalHeight = (maxWidth.toFloat() / ratioBitmap).toInt()
        }
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this, finalWidth, finalHeight, true)
    } else this
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Added RESIZE_CROP to Gowrav's answer.

```
   enum RequestSizeOptions {
    RESIZE_FIT,
    RESIZE_INSIDE,
    RESIZE_EXACT,
    RESIZE_CENTRE_CROP
}
static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, RequestSizeOptions options) {
    try {
        if (reqWidth > 0 && reqHeight > 0 && (options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_FIT ||
                options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE ||
                options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_EXACT || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_CENTRE_CROP)) {

            Bitmap resized = null;
            if (options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_EXACT) {
                resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
            } else {
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                float scale = Math.max(width / (float) reqWidth, height / (float) reqHeight);
                if (scale > 1 || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_FIT) {
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (width / scale), (int) (height / scale), false);
                }
                if (scale > 1 || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_CENTRE_CROP) {
                    int smaller_side = (height-width)>0?width:height;
                    int half_smaller_side = smaller_side/2;
                    Rect initialRect = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
                    Rect finalRect = new Rect(initialRect.centerX()-half_smaller_side,initialRect.centerY()-half_smaller_side,
                            initialRect.centerX()+half_smaller_side,initialRect.centerY()+half_smaller_side);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,  finalRect.left, finalRect.top, finalRect.width(), finalRect.height(), null, true);
                    //keep in mind we have square as request for cropping, otherwise - it is useless
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
                }

            }
            if (resized != null) {
                if (resized != bitmap) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                return resized;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("AIC", "Failed to resize cropped image, return bitmap before resize", e);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it gives the temporary solution.  RESIZE_INSIDE would solve my problem but that is missing in the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

[This is an awesome library from ArthurHub](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) to handle the image crops both programmatically and interactively if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

But if you prefer a non bloated version like me.., the internal function shown here is a rather sophisticated to perform Image Scaling with few standard options

```
/**
 * Resize the given bitmap to the given width/height by the given option.<br>
 */

enum RequestSizeOptions {
    RESIZE_FIT,
    RESIZE_INSIDE,
    RESIZE_EXACT
}

static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, RequestSizeOptions options) {
    try {
        if (reqWidth > 0 && reqHeight > 0 && (options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_FIT ||
                options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE ||
                options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_EXACT)) {

            Bitmap resized = null;
            if (options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_EXACT) {
                resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
            } else {
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                float scale = Math.max(width / (float) reqWidth, height / (float) reqHeight);
                if (scale > 1 || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_FIT) {
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (width / scale), (int) (height / scale), false);
                }
            }
            if (resized != null) {
                if (resized != bitmap) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                return resized;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("AIC", "Failed to resize cropped image, return bitmap before resize", e);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: and how to implement the "Resize inside"

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int wantedWidth, int wantedHeight) {
    float originalWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    float originalHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(wantedWidth, wantedHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    Matrix m = new Matrix();

    float scalex = wantedWidth/originalWidth;
    float scaley = wantedHeight/originalHeight;
    float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (wantedHeight - originalHeight * scaley)/2.0f;

    m.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
    m.preScale(scalex, scaley);
    // m.setScale((float) wantedWidth / bitmap.getWidth(), (float) wantedHeight / bitmap.getHeight());
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was this, which maintains aspect ratio, and requires only one size, for example if you have a 1920*1080 and an 1080*1920 image and you want to resize it to 1280, the first will be 1280*720 and the second will be 720*1280

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitmap(final Bitmap temp, final int size) {
        if (size > 0) {
            int width = temp.getWidth();
            int height = temp.getHeight();
            float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
            int finalWidth = size;
            int finalHeight = size;
            if (ratioBitmap < 1) {
                finalWidth = (int) ((float) size * ratioBitmap);
            } else {
                finalHeight = (int) ((float) size / ratioBitmap);
            }
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
        } else {
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple math involved in rescaling the image, consider the following snippet and follow along,
1. Suppose, you have Imaan image with 720x1280 and you want to to be fit in 420 width, get the percentage of reduction required by given math,

```
originalWidth = 720;
wP = 720/100;
/*  wP = 7.20 is a percentage value */
```

2. Now subtract the required width from original width and then multiply the outcome by `wP`. You will get the percentage of width being reduced.

`difference = originalWidth - 420;
dP = difference/wP;`

Here `dP` will be 41.66, means you are reducing the size 41.66%. So you have to reduce the height by 41.66(`dP`) to maintain the ration or scale of that image.
Calculate the height as given below,

```
hP = originalHeight / 100;
//here height percentage will be 1280/100 = 12.80
height = originalHeight - ( hp * dP);
// here 1280 - (12.80 * 41.66) = 746.75
```

Here is your fitting scale, you can resize image/Bitmap in 420x747. It will return the resized image without losing the ratio/scale.

**Example**

```
public static Bitmap scaleToFit(Bitmap image, int width, int height, bool isWidthReference) {
    if (isWidthReference) {
        int originalWidth = image.getWidth();
        float wP = width / 100;
        float dP = ( originalWidth - width) / wP;
        int originalHeight = image.getHeight();
        float hP = originalHeight / 100;
        int height = originalHeight - (hP * dP);
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    } else {
        int originalHeight = image.getHeight();
        float hP = height / 100;
        float dP = ( originalHeight - height) / hP;
        int originalWidth = image.getWidth();
        float wP = originalWidth / 100;
        int width = originalWidth - (wP * dP);
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }
    return image;
}
```

here you are simply scaling the image with reference of height or width parameter to fit into required criteria.