# Re-size Image maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am attempting to re-size an image and maintain its aspect ratio the bitmap mBitmap measures 1200x539 and I need to reduce this to about 1/3rd of that.

```
 mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;

                int H = (int)mBitmap.getHeight();      
                int W =(int)mBitmap.getWidth();            
                nBitmap = BitmapScaler.setBitmapScale(mBitmap, W,H);
```

I spotted this answer provided by Streets Of Boston and have attempted to use it in my app but I may have messed up the variables and I am getting a blank image the same size as the original,  can anyone show me how to achieve this correctly?

[Scaled Bitmap maintaining aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440647/scaled-bitmap-maintaining-aspect-ratio)

The code runs without error but returns an image the same size as the original!

```
public static Bitmap setBitmapScale(Bitmap originalImage, int width, int height){

            Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Config.ARGB_8888);
            float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth(), originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
            float scale = width/originalWidth;
            float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale)/2.0f;
            Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
            transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
            transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);
            return background;
      }
```

Comment: Hi Ali, Many thanks for your code snippets this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are two functions I am using for my own purpose, this might help you

```
/************************ Calculations for Image Sizing *********************************/ 
public Drawable ResizeImage (int imageID) { 

int newWidth = 1000; //This is new width which can be (1/3) * orignalWidth

double ratio = deviceWidth / imageWidth; 
int newImageHeight = (int) (imageHeight * ratio); 

Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageID); 
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),getResizedBitmap(bMap,newImageHeight,(int) deviceWidth)); 

return drawable; 
}

/************************ Resize Bitmap *********************************/ 
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) { 

int width = bm.getWidth(); 
int height = bm.getHeight(); 

float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width; 
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height; 

// create a matrix for the manipulation 
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 

// resize the bit map 
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight); 

// recreate the new Bitmap 
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false); 

return resizedBitmap; 
}
```

Comment: Image getting blur when resize, i have image which size is 175*210 and i want to resize as 480*720