# Wallpapers are auto cropped after applying

Tags: java, android, xml, wallpaper

I compiled a wallpaper app from a source code, inserted some 1230x720 pictures, But when I applied the walls using that app, they always get cropped automatically. What should I change in the code to apply at the original size and resolution?

Here's an example:
1.Original Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziSBt.jpg

2.After applying as an wallpaper using my app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/19xMQ.jpg

Source code: blog.blundell-apps.com/set-phone-wallpaper/

Thanks

EDIT: this code in HeavyLifter.java seems to be the culprit, how do I change it to "Fit the screen resolution"?

```
private Bitmap getImage(int resourceId) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, null);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, manager.getDesiredMinimumWidth(),   manager.getDesiredMinimumHeight(), true);
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspect ratio of the image (720x1230) and manager.getDesiredMinimumWidth() to  manager.getDesiredMinimumHeight() (720x1280) are not the same and so the image gets distorted.

So eighter provide a image with a fitting aspect ratio or crop the image before applying the scaling operation

Comment: Can you please tell me how to keep the aspect ratio. I'm noob :-(

Comment: I can fit correctly into my phone's screen from the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440647/scaled-bitmap-maintaining-aspect-ratio?rq=1
But not sure if it will be correct for other phones with different res

Comment: yes, that's what you have to do. You might want to replace the 4096 with maximum of width and height from the devices screen size. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)